# Building PhoneGap/Cordova plugin with a non-redistributable library

Tags: cordova

The online PhoneGap/Cordova builder apparently requires that your plugin 
source and dependencies be accessible in a public GitHub repo.  My plugin requires a vendor library that I'm licensed to distribute as part of an app, but I don't think I'm allowed to redistribute the library jar by itself.

Is there any way I can use the online builder without checking the jar into a public GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "online builder" you mean phonegap build, if you purchase a paid plan you can upload private plugins that only you can use.

https://build.phonegap.com/plans

Comment: And then we would build the plugin locally instead of uploading the source to GitHub?  I really know nothing about how all this works.  I'm just an Android guy who was told to write a Cordova plugin ASAP.

Comment: No, you upload it to phonegap build site and it's private